# Output duplicates records in batch script

Tags: arrays, batch-file, output

Trying to output filename, record count, sort csv on column L and displace the first record fullname and last record fullname for each csv in directory.

I am trying to print out an array that contain zip, first name,last name. The logic of my script is to read in the specific column for source csv. I am able to output the file name and record count. However I can seen to get the correct first record fullname and last record fullname. As you can see from my sample data there is duplication.

Sample:

> ```
>    Filename: Test1.csv
>    Record Count: 988
>    First Record Name: 12025, Jeff, Meacham 
>    Last Record Name: 14905, Jazzlynn, Doe
>
>    Filename: Test2.csv
>    Record Count: 580
>    First Record Name: 12010, Jim, Palmerino 
>    Last Record Name: 14905, Jazzlynn, Doe
>
>    Filename: Test3.csv
>    Record Count: 522
>    First Record Name: 12010, Jim, Palmerino 
>    Last Record Name: 14905, Joseph, Panosian
>
>    Filename: Test4.csv
>    Record Count: 555
>    First Record Name: 12010, jim, Palmerino 
>    Last Record Name: 14905, Joseph, Thurber
> ```

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

IF EXIST result3.txt DEL /F result3.txt


for %%f in (*csv) do (
   set CurrentFile=%%f
   set /a NumLines=0
    

     for /f %%j in ('Find "" /v /c ^< !CurrentFile!') Do (
       Set /a NumLines=%%j
    )
        


    for /F "tokens=1-12 delims=," %%a in (!CurrentFile!) do (
 
        if not defined counter set counter=0
        set /a counter+=1
        set line[%%~lcounter]=%%l, %%d, %%f
        
    )

    (set row=%~1) & (set last=%~1)
    for /F "tokens=1-2 delims==" %%a in ('set line[') do (
        
    if not defined row (set row=%%b ) else (set last=%%b )
        set row=!row:"=!
        set last=!last:"=!  
         )
        
       echo.    
       echo.   Filename: !CurrentFile!
           echo.   Record Count: !NumLines!
           echo.   First Record Name: !row!
           echo.   Last Record Name: !last!
         
    ) >> result3.txt
    
    

) 

ENDLOCAL
```

> ```
>    Filename: Test1.csv
>    Record Count: 988
>    First Record Name: 12025, Jeff, Meacham 
>    Last Record Name: 14905, Jazzlynn, Doe
>
>    Filename: Test2.csv
>    Record Count: 580
>    First Record Name: 12010, Jim, Palmerino 
>    Last Record Name: 14905, Matthew  Smalles
>
>    Filename: Test3.csv
>    Record Count: 522
>    First Record Name: 12010, Joshua Long
>    Last Record Name: 14905, Joseph, Panosian
>
>    Filename: Test4.csv
>    Record Count: 555
>    First Record Name: 12010, Hillary Koller
>    Last Record Name: 14905, Joseph, Thurber
> ```

Comment: You need ask more direct questions and I would divide concur your problems. You asking whether why some fields getting duplicated? Duplicated across multiple files? duplicate file reads?

Comment: Yes why are values duplicated across multiple files. Seem like the data is not clearing after each file is ran.

Comment: I just notice something, when I specific one file at a time the script runs as desired. It seem the trouble is for %%f in (*csv) do (
   set CurrentFile=%%f

Comment: Do you mean `*.csv` rather than `*csv` (note the dot)?

Comment: You could avoid removing quotation marks from `row` and `last` when you used `%%~b` rather than `%%b`, I guess. And I think you could avoid delayed expansion when you used `for` variables (like `%%f`) instead of variables (like `CurrentFile`), except for the `echo` block, of course. What I do not understand is this: `set line[%%~lcounter]=...`...

Comment: set line[%%~lcounter] as an array to store the zip in sorted order. I figure that might be any issue with that code. I need to make sure it is empty on each run. I check the code and notice that record from previous files are showing up in the line array. Is there way to reset an array to empty?

Comment: To example my train of thought. I am using the zip code value and a counter as index for the array. This will allow me to sort the data using the array feature of order index. Thus the zip code and data will be in the ascending sort order. Then I can grab the first and last record from each file in the sorted order.

Comment: This issue now is that the code populating the array set line[%%~lcounter]=%%l, %%d, %%f is appending each file data to the array. I would prefer the array to reset to null each time a new file is ran.

Comment: I figure it out, I just append the current file name to the array so each time a new array is created. ('set line_!CurrentFile![')

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding to current file name to the array name. Thus creating a new array each time.
('set line_!CurrentFile![')